# Adding an index to a Core Data table view [iPhone, table views]

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view which is grouped according to month and year. For this I have created a transient attribute and a corresponding sort descriptor in the NSFetchedResultsController which helps me in grouping according to the month and year. The table view  is working perfectly and displaying the sections just as I want (using titleForHeaderInSection).

I want to add an index to the table view, and I'm currently stalled here. I believe the only way to do this is by:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

So how do I give it an array of all the section names?

P.S.: This is my first post.

Comment: yep, please post your findings and mark your own answer. Otherwise people will continue to read your question hoping to help supply an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
if (lastSectionIndex == -1) {
    return nil;
}
NSMutableArray *sectionNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *sectionName = nil;
for (int i = 0; i <= lastSectionIndex; i++) {
    sectionName = [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:i] name];
    [sectionNames addObject:sectionName];
}
return sectionNames;
```

}

Comment: A much shorter version of this would be `return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] valueForKeyPath:@"name"];`.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. That's actually what I was looking for. I was confused between the property "name" and the key "name".